# Calculate the change percent of a sliding time window in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch newbie here. I have a series of log messages like these

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "whatever",
  "type": "toBeMonitored",
  "success": true
}
```

I was tasked to react on a change of -30% of the total amount of successful messages compared to yesterday's same interval. So if I do the check at 8 AM today, I should compare today's total count from midnight to 8 AM to yesterday's same interval.

I tried creating a date histogram aggregation but I would like to have the diff percentage as a query result and not do the math on the development side.

```json
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "toBeMonitored"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lte": "now/h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
       "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Better do it on application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up dropping the `date_histogram` aggregation and using the `date_range` one. It's much easier to work with, even though it does not return the difference compared to yesterday's same time period. I did that in code.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "toBeMonitored"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lte": "now/h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ranged_documents": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "key": "yesterday",
            "from": "now-1d/d",
            "to": "now-24h/h"
          },
          {
            "key": "today",
            "from": "now/d",
            "to": "now/h"
          }
        ],
        "keyed": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would yield a result similar to the one below

```json
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 42,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 42,
        "skipped": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [],
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null
    },
    "took": 134,
    "timed_out": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "ranged_documents": {
            "buckets": {
                "yesterday": {
                    "from_as_string": "2020-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "doc_count": 268300,
                    "to_as_string": "2020-10-12T12:00:00.000Z",
                    "from": 1602460800000,
                    "to": 1602504000000
                },
                "today": {
                    "from_as_string": "2020-10-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "doc_count": 251768,
                    "to_as_string": "2020-10-13T12:00:00.000Z",
                    "from": 1602547200000,
                    "to": 1602590400000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the [`derivative` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html) to achieve exactly what you expect:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "toBeMonitored"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lte": "now/h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
       "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "successDiff": {
          "derivative": {
            "buckets_path": "_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In each bucket you're going to get the difference between the document count in the previous bucket vs the current bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was also looking at the derivative aggregation. Unfortunately it doesn't really as I still have to loop through all the results on the app side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If you specify the correct interval size, you'll have only the two buckets you're interested in and in the second one you're going to have the diff you're after

Comment: See my own response below